# Not able to set "top" and "left" attributes of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, setattribute

I have created a chrome extension which appends three small buttons on hovering a larger button (circle buttons). I would like to position the buttons such as that of a half radial menu. However, no matter what I do , the top and left attributes of the three buttons aren't getting set. I have also set the attribute "position" to 'absolute' but that isn't getting set either for the three buttons.

I have tried:

```
1)button.setAttribute("style","top:20px");
2)button.style.setProperty("top","-20px");
3)$(button).css("top","-20px");
4)button.style.top = "-20";
5)button.style.top = -20 + "px";
```

I'm able to set all other attributes like color, background-color,border,display etc. What could be the problem?

Here's how I'm creating the small button:

```
  var btnOne = document.createElement('button');
  btnOne.setAttribute("id","b1");
  var textOne = document.createElement('span');
  textOne.textContent = '10';
  btnOne.style.position = "absolute";
  btnOne.style.setProperty("top","-20px");
  btnOne.style.setProperty("left","-25px");
  textOne.style.color = ColorCode
  btnOne.setAttribute("style","display:block; border:1px solid #ccc; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 50%; transition: background-color 0.5s ease");
  btnOne.appendChild(textOne);
```

(ColorCode is a variable)

As you can see from the snippet below, on hovering the largeButton, the small button(btnOne) should get appended to the div 'element', an element present on a particular webpage, whose child is the largeButton. It does get appended, however, the three small buttons appear as a vertical list right below the large button rather than at the specified positions. I chose to append the small buttons to the div element because it has a constant class whereas the class of the largeButton keeps changing.

```
   var element = document.getElementsByClassName("u-relative u-foreground")[5];
   $(largeButton).hover(function(e) {

          if (!element.contains(btnOne)) {
           element.appendChild(btnOne);
           element.appendChild(btnTwo);
           element.appendChild(btnThree);
};
```

This shows how I'm appending for just one of the buttons.

Comment: Can you post the html please?

Comment: how are you *selecting* or *creating* the `button`?

Comment: I have **no idea** of chrome extensions, but **if** that works like regular CSS, you need to position the element in order to move it with top, left, etc. Try position:relative

Comment: @JoshAdams, hope the edited question is clearer.

Comment: @Bharadwaj, the edited question shows how I'm creating the button. All the attributes are getting set, except top and left.

Comment: You are overwriting the style attribute while you are setting the color and other stuff. Try adding `position` and other values inside the `setAttribute`

Comment: @Bharadwaj, thank you so much! Never knew that we had to set all attributes at once :)